# Reloading function issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am looking for some advice on my code below. Everything is working ok at the moment but the problem I have is that I have a table which reloads its data every 60 secs. I have other javascripts that alter my table contents however due to the reload I tried putting in the initializing code in my reload function as per below. Now for some reason the only way for this to work is if I have the initializing outside of my reload but also inside my reload function. If I try to remove either of them my javascript just breaks. The reason why I only want one is because part of the script hide certain data and when i first load up my page it tires to hide my data a few times until it finally settles. Its not really a deal breaker more than just annoying to me, just looking for some advice on this.

initializing code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var argObj = {
dateFormat:"d/m/yy",
decimalSeparator:".",
boolYesNoText:"Yes|No",
labelArr:["Save","Cancel","Clear"],
arrToEdit:[],
pinTableHeader:true,
hideIdColumn:true};
initCustomEditFunction(argObj); 
</script>
```

The reloading code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function reload() {
$.ajax({
async: false,
cache:false,
url: "http://ensemble-mtl.ent.cginet/sites/SERVIPCManagement/imc/Shared%20Documents/Whiteboard/Whiteboard-Inline.aspx",
complete: function (xData, Status) {
var DVWPMarkup = $(xData.responseText).find("#reload_me").html();
$("#reload_me").html(DVWPMarkup);
highlightcode_IM();
highlightcode_SM();
inline();
}
});
}

function highlightcode_IM()
{

$('.IM_last_modified').each(function () {
    var dtSt = $(this).html().split("/");
    var when = new Date([dtSt[1], dtSt[0], dtSt[2]].join("/"));
    var now = Date.now();

    if (now - when > 3600000) {
        $(this).addClass('min60');
    } else if (now - when > 1800000) {
        $(this).addClass('min30');
    } else if (now - when > 1000) {
        $(this).addClass('min1');
    } 

});
}

function highlightcode_SM()
{

$('.SM_next_update').each(function () {
    var dtSt = $(this).html().split("/");
    var when = new Date([dtSt[1], dtSt[0], dtSt[2]].join("/"));
    var current = new Date();

    if (when.getTime() - current.getTime() < 900000 && current < when) {
        $(this).addClass('min30');
    } else {
        if (current > when) {
            $(this).addClass('min60');
        }
    }
});
}

function inline()
{
var argObj = {
dateFormat:"d/m/yy",
decimalSeparator:".",
boolYesNoText:"Yes|No",
labelArr:["Save","Cancel","Clear"],
arrToEdit:[],
pinTableHeader:true,
hideIdColumn:true};
initCustomEditFunction(argObj); 
}

$(document).ready(function(){ 
reload();
var auto_refresh = setInterval(function(){reload();}, 60000); 
});
</script>
```

Comment: `$("#reload_me").html(DVWPMarkup);` will destroy all the contents of `#reload_me` and then generate new nodes based upon `DVWPMarkup`. If you have any _JavaScript_ linked to the destroyed nodes it won't automatically switch over and you need to re-attach it

Comment: Thanks Paul, I have 2 scripts to reference  '<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript" SRC="Scripts/Inline/InlineEditingForSP2007_23.js"></SCRIPT>' and ' <SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript" SRC="Scripts/Inline/spjs-utility.js"></SCRIPT>' how would I reference those in my inline function?